# Version conflict updating to play-services 9.4.0

Tags: android

```
  Receive   Error
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':applock:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of                 google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

```
In top level build gradle:

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

In app level build gradle:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'


  I have also include
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
in the end of the build gradle file.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> [...]updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0.

Like that?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
```

Comment: How to get permission from FireBase?

Answer (score 0):

change

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'`

to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'`

Comment: OK Thanks, How to get permission from FireBase?

Comment: what type of permission do you need ?

Comment: I need permission to grand service to run at the background

Comment: For that you need to create a **services**. To tell you that it requires lot's of steps to follow. follow this [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) steps to add background services to your app.